# Remove columns from data frame that only contain zeros

Tags: r

I'm trying to recreate a data frame (DC5_prod) that has hundreds of columns, but many without any values other than zero.

The first column in the data frame is text and the rest are numeric.  Is there a way to ignore the first column while simultaneously eliminating the remainder of columns that are composed entirely of zeros?

```
DC5_Prod
 a   b c d e f   
1 AK 0 0 0 0 1 
2 JI 0 0 0 0 0
```

The above is a snippet of how it currently stands and would want an output of:

```
DC5_Prod
 a    f   
1 AK  1 
2 JI  0
```

When I attempt to utilize the solution issued on a similar question on the site:

```
DC5_prod[, colSums(DC5_prod != 0) > 0]
```

just essentially returns the first column without removing any.

Comment: Using your original line of thought `DC5_Prod[,-(which(colSums(DC5_Prod[2:ncol(DC5_Prod)]) == 0)+1)]` not very elegant if more of your columns have characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this R base approach

```
> ind <- sapply(DC5_Prod, function(x) sum(x==0)) != nrow(DC5_Prod)
> DC5_Prod[,ind]
   a f
1 AK 1
2 JI 0
```